# MotionEvent : can it capture clicks on any active application on Screen

Tags: android, sdk, motionevent

can Android's MotionEvent give out the coordinates (X,Y) of user interaction on the screen irrespective of the application that's running on the device.

thanks.

Comment: Nooooooo. Only the window/activity where click has happened will receive that event.

Comment: that i understood @Vishal Arora. The thing i want to know is will it listen to the user click on the app the event is declared on or does it track the clicks on a different app as well for example instagram.

Comment: How do you mean in case of instagram ?

Comment: does MotionEvent give me the coordinates of where the user clicked if he is doing some actions on a third party app.

Comment: No, it doesn't.